# OSX-like mission control for linux

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, multi-monitor, macos

I am using ubuntu 18 switching from OSX.

In OSX mission control there is a feature where each monitor has its own "workspace" that can be independently switched between.

GNOME3 has a similar feature where you can either switch between workspaces on your main monitor, or using gnome tweaks (under workspaces>workspaces span displays) you can switch between workspaces across all of your monitors at once.

This doesn't quite replicate the functionality of the workspace on OSX however, because OSX allows you to switch between workspaces on each monitor independently. For example, on my side monitor, in OSX I could have a code window that I want to remain persistent across multiple workspaces on the other monitors.

Is there an extension or windows manager that has this functionality for ubuntu?

EDIT: This is what I mean:

[image]
A window manager where:

1. Multiple workspaces exist
2. Workspaces can span multiple monitors
3. Workspaces can be switched independently

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but workspaces are a fairly standard concept across window managers.  [This](https://people.gnome.org/~bmsmith/build/overview-workspaces.html) might help.

---

If you're willing to test out another WM, both i3 and XFCE might have what you're describing.

Comment: I am looking for a windows manager that can do separate workspaces for each monitor, that can be switched between independantly. GNOME allows either seperate workspaces for the main monitor, or seperate workspaces across all monitors (but not independantly). i3 also does not have this feature. XFCE seems to have the same issue: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/different-workspaces-on-different-monitor-xfce-de/78185/6

Comment: i3 provides both 1 & 3 of your specs (some configuration required).  I'm not aware of any WM whose workspaces can span multiple monitors (2).